# How can I reset amp-states after submitting form or on click to go back to the page (Safari)?

Tags: safari, amp-html

I am using amp-states on jsp page. I change text of button to 'Loading...' on submitting form, then redirects me to another page. When I click to go back, I see that the button text is still 'Loading...'. That is, the state is not reset to the initial value. I use submit-success for reseting state(isLoading), but it is not work. This bug is reproducible in Safari and Firefox, it is not reproduced in Google Chrome. Why is this happening? How to fix it? I am ready to consider alternative options, without amp-states.

```
<amp-state id="testState">
    <script type="application/json">
    {
        "isLoading": false
    }
    </script>
</amp-state>

<div class="my-class" role="button">
    <form
        id="test"
        class="buysell-form"
        action="nextPageUrl"
        method="GET"
        target="_top"
        on="
            submit:
                AMP.setState({testState: {
                    isLoading: true
                }});
            submit-success:
                AMP.setState({testState: {
                    isLoading: false
                }});
            submit-error:
                AMP.setState({testState: {
                    isLoading: false
                }});
            invalid:
                AMP.setState({testState: {
                    isLoading: false
                }});"
        custom-validation-reporting="show-first-on-submit">

        <div class="inputs">
            <input type="text" class="location-input" title="Enter your city">
            <input
                type="submit"
                value="My button"
                [value]="testState.isLoading ? 'Loading...' : 'My button'"
                class="next-button"
                [class]="testState.isLoading ? 'next-button disabled' : 'next-button'"
                [disabled]="testState.isLoading">
        </div>  

    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to provide a link to a full working example so we can see the log entries. but if this works in chrome and fails in other browsers, file an issue with amp.dev - they jump on these kinds of issues quickly. but they/we can't help if you do not provide access to the page-in-question.

Comment: You can see the live example on the site https://www.upnest.com/re/ You should enter some city and click on button, then you see 'Loading on the button'. Then if you click to go back to preview page, you will see that the button did not return to 'Compare Agent'